# Removing muted attribute doesn't restore sound

Tags: javascript, html, video

I want a video to load automatically with no sound, then when clicking a button that says "Watch with Sound" I want the video to immediately start again from the beginning, with sound.

Here is the javascript.

```
let videoButton = document.querySelector("#video_button");
let video = document.querySelector("video") 

videoButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
video.pause();
video.currentTime = 0;
video.play();
video.removeAttribute("muted");
});
```

Clicking our button does indeed remove the `muted` attribute, and starts the video from the beginning, but there is still no sound.

What is wrong and how can it be made to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try setting the `muted` *attribute* to `false` to enable the sound:

```
video.muted = false;
```

Comment: Thank you! I had a thought about trying to set the boolean value explicitly somehow, but I didn't know how to express it.